# Can I buy a local SIM in South Korea that enables tethering?

Tags: cellphones, south-korea, data-plans

I will stay for a week or more in Seoul, and want to get a local SIM in my iPhone. As far as I know, [there don't seem to exist](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Korea,_Republic_of_(South)) any carriers that enable tethering, as it is not mentioned there (but it was in other countries' page [like Hong Kong](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Hong_Kong)).

Also, it seems that the regulation is too strict in South Korea for a traveler to get local SIM working. Is tethering allowed for a traveler or only for a local citizen, or not allowed for both?

I want to use tethering from my iPhone to MacBook; 4G/LTE is a must; unlimited data plan and no speed cap or suspension for excessive use is highly appreciated.

---

*Please don't consider getting through Wi-Fi only even if Seoul is filled with great public Wi-Fi; it's my inquisitiveness of trying [the best network in the world](https://opensignal.com/reports/2015/09/state-of-lte-q3-2015/), too!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it in my recent trip to Seoul. You can buy the SIM card from KT olleh and use it for tethering. I asked the staff at counter if I can use tethering, and she kindly replied "Yes".

And now I'm writing this answer on my MacBook via tethering. It's 4G/LTE, unlimited, and likely no speed cap or restriction, but for me it seems a bit slow, but OK.

---

By the way, [the linked page](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Korea,_Republic_of_(South)) says the following but it is **NOT correct**:

> SIM card rental
>
> They rent out a data-only prepaid SIM and a general prepaid SIM with voice and data. Both SIMs include "unrestricted" data use during the rental period. You need to link your credit card and in case of loss ₩ 10,000 will be charged. Remember, you need to give or sent back their SIM. Rental rates for both SIM cards are:
>
> for 5 days: ₩ 25,000
>
> for 10 days: ₩ 35,000
>
> for 30 days: ₩ 65,000

Actually, only prepaid SIM with voice and data is a rental type. Data-only SIM is purchasable and doesn't need to be returned. I purchased the data-only SIM. The price is the same for both cards, for your information.